# Replace each key in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have this code:

```
prefix = "!"
admin_commands = {"hello" => ""}
if admin_commands.length > 0
  admin_commands.map! { |command| prefix + command }
end
```

How would I change the key `"hello"` in `admin_commands` to `"!hello"`?

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values

Comment: You mean "key", not "value".

Comment: @sawa: also it's not an array.

Comment: Then what is it?

Comment: It's called a hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ruby >= 2.5

```
admin_commands.transform_keys!{|k| prefix + k}
```

Otherwise:

```
prefix = "!"
admin_commands = {"Hello" => ""}
admin_commands = admin_commands.map {|k, v| [prefix + k, v]}.to_h
```

This method maps each key/value pair of the hash to an array, effectively returning an array of pair, which is then transformed back to an hash using `to_h`

Comment: just got downvoted, care to explain why? So I can improve my post and provide better answer

Comment: ```NameError: undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object```. Lesson: Copy and paste does not always work.

Comment: Instead of map+to_h, it is _probably_ better to use reduce/each_with_object.

Comment: @sawa I added another solution first, and then added `transform_keys!`, while precising that it's not available to all ruby version. But yeah, I copied pasted the block because that was easier haha

Comment: @SergioTulentsev wouldn't enumerating on the hash always return an array of pairs?

Comment: @Geoffroy: each key-value pair is yielded to the enumerator block, yes. No need to keep all of them in a temp array.

Answer (score 3):

```
admin_commands.transform_keys{|k| prefix + k}
```

Comment: This is for 2.5+

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity:

```
admin_commands.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), hash|
  hash["#{prefix}#{k}"] = v
end
#⇒ {"!Hello"=>""}
admin_commands.
  keys.
  map(&prefix.method(:+)).
  zip(admin_commands.values).
  to_h
#⇒ {"!Hello"=>""}
```